# Slow running firebase function with Invalid query string segment:

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a simple firebase function which is reading a very small amount of data (less than 1kb) but it is taking nearly 2 seconds to complete and has a warning in the logs `FIREBASE WARNING: Invalid query string segment:`

The result is 200 OK, however something strange is clearly going on, a

```
   import express from 'express';
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"
const cors = require('cors')();
const api = express();

 const getJob = async (req, res) => {
    const { organisation, job } = req.params

    console.log("READING", req.params)
    console.log("one", `careers/jobs/${organisation}/${job}`)

    const jobContent = await admin.database().ref(`careers/jobs/${organisation}/${job}`).once("value")

    if (!jobContent) {
        res.sendStatus(404)
    }

    console.log("two")
    const descriptionContent =await admin.database().ref(`careers/descriptions/${organisation}/${job}`).once("value")

    return res.send({
        ...jobContent.val(),
        description: descriptionContent && descriptionContent.val()
    })

}


api.use(cors);

api.get('/careers/:organisation/jobs/:job', getJob)


export const careersApi = functions.https.onRequest(api)
```

firebase.json

```
    {
  "functions": {
    "source": "build"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/careers/**",
        "function": "careersApi"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Firebase SDK and the CLI to deploy this?  It doesn't look like a Firebase style Cloud Function.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson yep - it is part of a larger express app which lives on the function.

Comment: Log the values of all the variables in use here.  What exactly are the strings you're building here?

Comment: 6:01:35.726 PM
info 
careersApi
one careers/jobs/verv/another-id

Comment: 6:01:35.726 PM
info 
careersApi
READING { organisation: 'verv', job: 'another-id' }|

Comment: above are the logs from firebase console - (i did the logging earlier)

Comment: FYI you can edit the question instead writing in comments.  It's easier to read things that way.

Comment: So how do you know this bit of code is responsible?  You said there's more code.  I suggest you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem, so that others can copy it and run it on their own to duplicate the issue.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson - Have expanded the code.

Comment: How are you invoking the function? What's the path of the URL?

Comment: Https;//api.mydomian.com/careers/verv/jobs/another-id

Comment: With my firebase.json routing careers/** to careersApi function

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your full firebase.json with all the rewrites?

Comment: Updated with firebase.json :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Invalid query string segment` warning looks like a [recently introduced bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/517) which will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: Cool - could this be causing the slow run also?

Comment: No, I wouldn't have thought so. Have you used the devtools performance profiler to identify any bottlenecks?

Comment: Its a function so how can devtools help here? Running in my local machine using "firebase serve --only functions" the function executes in 35ms

Comment: Sorry, I was focusing on the database rather than Functions. Anyhow, it looks as though functionality is unaffected. See Matt Goodrich's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48857480/3904310)